# How to push or present UIViewcontroller or storyboard from UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

What I did:

1. I am using scrollview to view some `UIView`(s), with paging enabled.
2. In last page in subview of scrollView I added a button.
3. I also wrote a function which is in subclass of `UIView` ,which is invoked when we press that button.
4. I want to view storyboard when I press that button.

Comment: U want to present viewController from your storyboard ? or whole storyboard that exist in your xcode ? Please correct my understanding.

Comment: I want to present my storyboard or a viewController ..from a UIView subclass.. In UIView subclass i added a button with the help of drawRect: and now when i press that button i want my storyboard  or a UIViewcontroller before my eyes...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement protocol method for custom UIView class.

For example;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol YourCustomViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)buttonTapped;

@end

@interface YourCustomView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) id< YourCustomViewDelegate > delegate;

@end
```

And the .m file you can call buttonTapped delegate method.

```
- (void)myCustomClassButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate buttonTapped];
}
```

For proper work;

- set your custom view delegate to self in your custom view controller.
- add buttonTapped method to that view controller
- And do what you want in that method. Present/Push view controllers like the other answers explained.

**Edit**

I will try to illustrate very simple usage of protocols, hope it will help you.

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "YourCustomView.h"

@interface MyViewController ()<YourCustomViewDelegate> // this part is important

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    YourCustomView *customView = // initialize your custom view, I suppose that you already did it
    customView.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)buttonTapped
{
    YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_CLASS *viewCon =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainVC"];    //mainVC is just a example and u will have to replace it with your viewController storyboard id

    //Pushing VC
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewCon animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for u valuable reply...but i am not famlier with protocols...can u plz answer in detail that how to set my custom view delegate to self in custim view controller...and how to ad buttonTapped methid to the viewController and how to modify buttontapped method ..thanks in advance

Comment: I tried that ..first i just put a NSLog in button tapped..i can't even print it in log when i tap that button

Comment: Are you sure that set the delegate like customView.delegate = self;? @Lalli_Mann there should work if you set delegate to self and of course import that delegate.(MyViewController ()<YourCustomViewDelegate>)

Comment: Yea i added mycustomview.delegate=self in viewDidLoad ...imported mycustomdelegate ..may be problem is in my action..thanks

Comment: I think..viewDidLoad is not called thats why we are unable to assign delegate to self

Comment: It is impossible that viewDidLoad is not called. MyViewController is the VC that has your custom view right? Not the pushed one?. If so, and your view is appeared on the screen, then viewDidLoad is called. You can just debug it.(setting breakpoint or just adding NSLog)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

```
    YourViewController *obj=[[YourViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obj];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController* initialView = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to set a storyboard Id to your ViewController, namely "mainVC". Then you could pus/present it using below code :-

```
 YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_CLASS *viewCon =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainVC"];    //mainVC is just a example and u will have to replace it with your viewController storyboard id

//Pushing VC
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewCon animated:YES];
//OR presenting VC
[self presentViewController:viewCon animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also in case if you want your another storyboard to be initiated then below,

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];   //Change MainStoryboard with your storyboard id
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help

the way i perceive your question is 
->Rightnow your inside you are in `UIView` class and inside it there is a button by clicking it  you want to push or present a ViewController and offcourse from inside your   UIView class you cant push or present your view Controller. So

you can do one simple thing  first inside action method make a ref(forward declaration) or you can make a whole new object  of your ViewController class  in which your UIView is present right  now , then call a function(which exist in your ViewController) like

//function inside your uiview calss

```
- (void)btnaction
{
     [_objCSInformationViewController pushViewController];
}
```

// function inside your view controller

```
-(void)pushViewController
{
yourViewController *objViewController = [[yourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourViewController" bundle:nil]; 
 [strong.navigationController pushViewController:objViewController animated:YES];

}
```