# Perform segue or presentviewcontroller from custom uiview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, segue

I looked at many stackoverflow answers and tried most of them. May be I am doing something wrong but if I can get clarified, it will be wonderful.

My viewcontroller LoginViewController has a method which gets called and custom alertview which is a uiview is shown to user. After user enters 4 digit pin, I need to call another view controller from that custom alertview (uiview).

My current setup is:

```
LoginViewController.h:

#import "LoginPinAlertView.h"

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <LoginPinAlertViewDelegate,... > {
LoginPinAlertView *customAlertView;
}

LoginViewController.m:

-(void) viewDidLoad {
 ...

 customAlertView.myLoginVC = self;
}
```

Inside my UI VIew (which a customer alert view)

```
LoginPinAlertView.h

@class LoginViewController 
...

@property (nonatomic, retain) LoginViewController *myLoginVC;

LoginPinAlertView.m

....
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
DestinationViewController *vc = [storyboard                instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyDestViewController"];
[vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self.myLoginVC presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
...
```

But this is not working right now. What my requirement is, from UI View (which is not part of any contorller because this is custom alert view which many controllers are using), I wish to push/present another view controller.

Comment: Could you please show more details on how you are calling the code to present the other view controller? Did you try debugging those lines of code? Try to check if the ```storyboard``` you are instantiating is not ```nil```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you ,

you cannot push/present view controller from a uiview class for it. you should check out this answer ,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26011073/3767017

Comment: Thanks Anurag for reply. I fixed this problem. Will post the solution in next comment.